# Node require - i don't understand this code

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm starting to learn node.js and mongoose and I do not understand the following code.

I have 2 files: app.js and idea.js

## app.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

require('./models/Idea')
const Idea = mongoose.model('ideas')
```

## idea.js

```
const mongoose1 = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose1.Schema

const IdeaSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: { type:String, required:true},
    details: {type:String, required:true},
    date: {type:Date, default:Date.now()}
  }
)
mongoose1.model('ideas', IdeaSchema)
```

When I run app.js, no error occurs. How is it possible? I did not export anything from the idea.js file!
How did the app.js file get access to the ideas model?

Comment: `require('./models/Idea')` will load (and run) `idea.js` and I assume (I'm not familiar with mongoose) that `mongoose1.model('ideas', IdeaSchema)` registers the `IdeaSchema` object which is then retrieved using `const Idea = mongoose.model('ideas')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` is cached. So, this:

```
let obj1 = require('an_object');
let obj2 = require('an_object');
```

will load the object in the first line, and return that same object from cache in the second line. This holds even if the two requires are in different files. Since `obj1` and `obj2` are references to the same object, if `obj1` gets modified, `obj2` also gets modified (because they're one and the same).

You did not export anything from Idea, but it doesn't matter; the purpose of Idea was to modify the mongoose object, not to return anything.

Simplified:

```
// storage.js
exports.hello = 'Mumble mumble';

// mod_storage.js
let modding_storage = require('./storage');
modding_storage.hello = "Hello, world!";

// main.js
let main_storage = require('./storage');
require('./mod_storage');
console.log(main_storage.hello);
// => Hello, world!
```

`mod_storage` changed `modding_storage`, but `modding_storage` is the same object as `main_storage`; change one, both change.